# Railo CFDOCUMENT: can't copy and paste from generated PDF

Tags: macos, pdf, coldfusion, railo, cfdocument

I simply make a PDF with

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" margintop="0.2" marginleft="0.4" marginright="0.3">
```

Resulting PDF is good, but under MAC OS X I can't copy text from it and paste elsewhere, for example in Text editor (it pastes whitespaces).

Do you think it's an encoding problem?